# Is there any R function to transpose row in a group to columns?

Tags: r

I want to do an analysis for each group in a row but it is a tedious way to filter each group.

My current data is like this after I have aggregate date data and group data to find the mean.

| group.1 | group.2 | x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.2.21 | A | 20 |
| 2.2.21 | A | 30 |
| 1.2.21 | B | 10 |
| 2.2.21 | B | 40 |

This is the ouput that i trying to do.

| DATE | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.2.21 | 20 | 10 |
| 2.2.21 | 30 | 40 |

I have try using tapply but it is not the output that i want.

Comment: There are tons of ways. Look at `stats::reshape`, or `data.table::dcast` or other ways in the tidyverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` package

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = group.2,
    values_from = x
  ) %>% 
  rename(DATE = group.1)
```

Output:

```
  DATE       A     B
  <chr>  <int> <int>
1 1.2.21    20    10
2 2.2.21    30    40
```

data:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group.1, ~group.2,  ~x,
  "1.2.21",      "A", 20L,
  "2.2.21",      "A", 30L,
  "1.2.21",      "B", 10L,
  "2.2.21",      "B", 40L
  )
```